# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled

Tags: java, connection, memory-leaks

I need help, pls.

I'm getting the next error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled.
```

The stack trace complete is:

```
java.util.Timer.sched(Timer.java:397)
java.util.Timer.schedule(Timer.java:193)
com.sun.gjc.util.StatementLeakDetector.startStatementLeakTracing(StatementLeakDetector.java:129)
com.sun.gjc.spi.base.PreparedStatementWrapper.(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:107)
com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.PreparedStatementWrapper40.(PreparedStatementWrapper40.java:64)
negocio.DAO.mfPersonas.PersonaInstitucionalDAO.obtenerPorId(PersonaInstitucionalDAO.java:30)
negocio.services.impl.PersonaInstitucionalServiceImpl.obtenerPorId(PersonaInstitucionalServiceImpl.java:28)
PortalHC.action.login.ActionRegistrarArea.action(ActionRegistrarArea.java:56)
PortalHC.action.ActionBase.execute(ActionBase.java:130)
negocio.DAO.Hibernation.doFilter(Hibernation.java:135)
```

My code in PersonaInstitucionalDAO is:

```
public static PersonaInstitucional obtenerPorId(Long idPersonaInstitucional) {
            return (PersonaInstitucional) Hibernation.getSession().get(PersonaInstitucional.class, idPersonaInstitucional);
}
```

And my Hibernation doFilter close the sessino of hibernate

Thanks very much,

I'm running a app Java on a glassfish 3.1.2 with Java 1.7

Ant suggestion?

Comment: Your exception seems valid. Where is your code?

Comment: I reckon this is a bug in the Glassfish JDBC connector code.  The Timer that has been cancelled is (I think) internal to that code.  At least, that's what the sourcecode on grepcode suggests.  http://grepcode.com/file/maven.java.net/content/groups/promoted/org.glassfish.main.jdbc.jdbc-ra.jdbc-core/jdbc-core/4.0-b68/com/sun/gjc/util/StatementLeakDetector.java/

Comment: Thanks, I wrote the complete stack trace and my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like a bug on the sun jbdc implementation. It is not clear if the wrapper is attempting to cancel the timer because it has already completed the execution, but it looks like it. Maybe you could attempt to configure Glassfish so that it does not check for Statement leaks.